# FFMPEG rotate command show black color on edges

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rotation

i am using command `ffmpeg -i NoAudio.mp4 -i cat-face-emoji.png -filter_complex "[1]rotate=a=140[ov1];[0][ov1]overlay=480:270" -c:a copy output.mp4 -y` to rotate image 140 degree but black background show on edges.

Here output video: https://app.dadan.io/video/share/nmmU8uiyCl2YVYm4

I am expecting to rotate image without any additional edges as the image in png.

Comment: Have you tried `c=none`? see [the doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `rotate` filter uses black color to fill the output area not covered by the rotated image. You may force it to not print background (`fillcolor=none`) or fill with any color with zero value of alpha component (`fillcolor=0x00000000`), e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y \
  -i NoAudio.mp4 \
  -i cat-face-emoji.png \
  -filter_complex "[1]rotate=a=140:fillcolor=0x00000000[ov1];[0][ov1]overlay=480:270" \
  output.mp4
```